# create html box with custom UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a specifci  of 600px x 800px dimension and I need the box with its very own scroll bar with custom UI. i dont want to use the browser's scrollbar as that would not gel with the rest of the design. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JScrollPane](http://code.google.com/p/jscrollpane/) (jQuery plugin) helps you style scrollbars, might be what you need.
Read this [blog](http://www.shahin.co.nr/jquery-plugin-to-style-scrollbars-cross-browser-compatible/) for example and opinion.

More info on [Kelvin's site](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html).

Answer (score 0):

Is it related to jQuery? If not, you can use CSS overflow: scroll in order to have your own scrollbar in a block element such as a div

```
<div style="width: 800px; height: 600px; overflow: scroll">something</div>
```